# neovim color scheme is causing everything to be very dark

Tags: neovim, color-scheme

Inside my `~/.config/nvim/` directory I have my `init.vim` file and another directory named `lua` which contains `plugins.lua` and I am using Packer to install the color schemes.

My `inti.vim` contains

```
lua require('plugins')

set background=dark
colorscheme gruvbox
```

and inside `~/.config/lua/plugins.lua` I have

```
packer = require 'packer'
packer.init{
}

local use = packer.use
packer.reset()

packer.startup(function()
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
  use "ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim"
end)
```

[image]

I have tried using Vundle to install the plugins and I also tried different color schemes and I keep getting the same thing.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @alpastor, did you ever find what caused the issue?

Comment: @Tim I needed to use a mac terminal that support 256 colors. I downloaded iTerm and everything started working